# Range unspecified in Rails validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, max

I have the following code in my model:

```
class Tweet < ActiveRecord::Base
 validates_length_of :content, length: { maximum: 140 }
```

and the following validation in my controller:

```
def new
  @tweet = Tweet.new
  @maximum_length = Tweet.validators_on( :content ).first.options[:maximum]
end
```

And I get the following error message in my browser. I have no idea what's wrong with this!

> Range unspecified. Specify the :in, :within, :maximum, :minimum, or :is option.

My view is:

```
<div class="form-group">

<%= form_for @tweet do |f| %>
chars left: <span id="counter" data-maximum-length = "<%=@maximum_length%>"<%= @maximum_length%></span>
<%= f.text_field :content, maxlength: @maximum_length, id: 'content' %>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
<%end%>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var content = $("#content");
  var counter = $("#counter");
  var max_length = counter.data("maximum_length");

  content.keyup(function(){
    counter.text(max_lnegth - $(this).val().length);
    });
  });
 </script>
```

Comment: You are mixing activemodel's `validates_length_of` helper with active record's `length` helper.

Answer (score 2):

Use `validates` instead. This is the preferred method for all validations (view the [Rails Validation Docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html)

```
validates :content, length: { maximum: 140 }
```

Using `validates_length_of` like you have in your code, it would be written as:

```
validates_length_of :content, maximum: 140
```

Answer (score 0):

```
validates_length_of :content, maximum: 140
```